# Could not create directory

Tags: plugins, updates, permissions

I have followed the instructions from

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WordPress
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-secure-updates-and-installations-in-wordpress-on-ubuntu

Every time I try to update or install a new plugin, I get the following error:

```
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/akismet.3.0.1.zip…
Unpacking the update…
An error occurred while updating Akismet: Could not create directory.
All updates have been completed.
```

I have set up `/var/www/html` with

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/wordpress /var/www/html
sudo chown wp-user:www-data -RL /var/www
sudo chmod g+w -R /var/www
```

I have tried

- Adding `define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/var/www/html/wp-content');` to `/etc/wordpress/config-my.host.php`
- `sudo chmod o+w -R /var/www/html/wp-content`
- `sudo -u wp-user touch /var/www/html/wp-content/test` succeeds
- `sudo -u www-data touch /var/www/html/wp-content/test` succeeds

System info:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

```
$ apt-show-versions wordpress apache2 php5 mysql-server
apache2:amd64/trusty 2.4.7-1ubuntu4 uptodate
mysql-server:all/trusty-security 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 uptodate
php5:all/trusty-security 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.3 uptodate
wordpress:all/trusty 3.8.2+dfsg-1 uptodate
```

Comment: You are using Ubuntu package for WordPress right? Had you tried conventional install (just downloading official WP archive and setting it up with LAMP)? PS if that 3.8.2 stands for WP version it's not current either.

Comment: @Rarst Weird! Downloading http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz and putting it at `/var/www/html` fixed the issue. Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Ubuntu package for WordPress right? Had you tried conventional install (just downloading official WP archive and setting it up with LAMP)?

While it's not very "Linux way" maybe, it's commonly suggested to stick with that for WordPress. I briefly dealt with Ubuntu WP package in the past and ended up doing just that as well.

PS if that 3.8.2 stands for WP version it's not current either.

Answer (score 0):

To create WordPress directory in Ubuntu server, you need to be in `var/www/` and its `sudo mkdir -p mysite.com/public_html && sudo chown -R user_name:www-data /var/www`

When you `ls` afterwards, you should see something like this:

```
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 microurb www-data 4096 Dec 15 06:36 html
drwxrwxr-x 3 microurb www-data 4096 Sep 23  2017 microurb.com
```